# How to Reference IHttpClientFactory in Blazor WebAssemly App?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, httpclientfactory

In VS 2019, I am trying to test using `HttpClient` in a Blazor WebAssemply App.  When creating the new Project, I selected the `.Net Core 3.1` option.  In the Program.cs, the `HttpClient` service is registered as following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

Under the "framework" section, `system.net.http` is listed.

We run into the problem of being unable to add `@inject IHttpClientFactory http` to a new Razor Component.  The error message was:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IHttpClientFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The online doc at Microsoft site shows the `IHttpClientFactory` is defined in the`System.Net.Http` package. What is the root cause of the errors I got and how can I fix it?

Comment: But why aren't you just injecting `HttpClient` instead?  That's kind of the idea for it to be scoped to the DI scope.

Comment: You don't need and don't want the factory pattern in a WebAssembly app.

Comment: Henk Holterman: "don't need and don't want..." And yet, IHttpClientFactory is used by default in the default template. You want to know why ? This merits a new question. Please create a new question and I'll try to answer it... ;}

Comment: I did try using the Microsoft.extension.http Nuget package.  The code was compiled successfully when using @inject IHttpClientFactory.  But, for some reason,  the razor page did not work.  So,  I give up using IHttpClientFactory and went back to use HttpClient and create WebAssembly app using .NET 5.  Please see more details in another post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805194/how-to-resove-error-related-to-httpclient-in-webassembly-app

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the following Nuget package: Microsoft.Extensions.Http