# How to Resove Error Related to HttpClient in WebAssembly App

Tags: httpclient, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to test HttpClient in a small WebAssemply App (created using .NET 5).
The program.cs contains following statement to add HttpClient service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

The source code of my test Razor Component is posted at the end. Following exception occurred when executing the statement: "HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(apiUrl)".  The same error occurred when using http.GetFromJsonAsync<>.
I was able to Web API to get data from same website in Blazor Server app.  For some reason, I could not make it work in WebAssembly app.  Any help will be appreciated.

## ERROR MESSAGE

> > mono_wasm_start_single_stepping 2
> > crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> > Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> > System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> > at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> > at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> > at WebAssemblyUseWebApi.Pages.Weather.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\projects\my_tryout\WebAssemblyUseWebApi\WebAssemblyUseWebApi\Pages\Weather.razor:line 27
> > at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> > at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
> > =============================================================================

## SOURCE CODE

```
page "/weather" 
@inject HttpClient http

<h3>Weather Data</h3>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
{
    <p>@errorMessage</p>
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
    <p>Loading ...</p>
}
else
{
    <p>@data</p>
}

@code {
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    public string data;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string apiUrl = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2471217/";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = response.ReasonPhrase;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the *full* exception text, not just parts of the stack trace. That `.Result` is a bug though. `OnInitializedAsync` is an async method, and so is `ReadAsStringAsync`. Use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved when I created an ASPCoreWebAPI app on the server side with following config settings in startup.cs program.  These settings allow the WebAssembly app  to retrieve data using HTTPClient.

```
1. In ConfigureServices, Add following
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "Open",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
});
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. In Configurations, add following
------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.UseCors("Open");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

That site does not seem to allow requests from a Browser.

There is no CORS header (access-control-allow-origin=...) in the response.

You can use either Blazor Serverside or add an API server to your WebAssembly project. Do have a look at the Wasm Hosted template before you try to reinvent the wheel.